# connection string problems when using Microsoft.AspNet.Identity to register users

Tags: c#, azure, visual-studio-2013, connection-string

I have a web forms project I created in Visual Studio 2013 that already has some login/register functionality for visitors to the website. I have managed to publish this basic website to my windows Azure account (currently a free trial).

My problem is that when I try to register a new user on the hosted website I see the following error

[image]

which occurs in the Register.aspx.cs file at the line highlighted in red. However I am able to register a user when I run the website locally from VS.

I imagine the problem is related to connection strings - the local web-site is configured correctly but the remote one is not. In this respect one thing I noticed is that my web.config file in the "Account" folder of my website (where Register.aspx.cs resides) has no connection string, whilst the Web.config file (outside of the Account folder) has the following;

```
<connectionStrings>
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=(LocalDb)\v11.0;Initial Catalog=aspnet-pharmastats-5fb46ce2-7e88-48da-8c6f-9e921f56e900;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\aspnet-pharmastats-5fb46ce2-7e88-48da-8c6f-9e921f56e900.mdf;Integrated Security=SSPI" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

I do not know if this is significant or not. However I have tried adding this connection string to the Account folder web.config folder but I still get the same error on the hosted website.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: The connection string is using localdb, which is a development database only available on your dev machine. In the cloud you'd need to create a SQL Azure database to store your data. Then override the connection string to point to your SQL Azure instance (can be done in the Azure portal web site settings, or using config transforms, or overridden during site deployment if publishing using Visual Studio).

Comment: Many thanks Anthony - this should have been obvious!